# Split vector of floats by whole integer value

Tags: r, vector

Suppose that I have a vector like the following

```
> head(samp)
[1] 1959.000 1959.083 1959.167 1959.250 1959.333 1959.417
> tail(samp)
[1] 1997.500 1997.583 1997.667 1997.750 1997.833 1997.917
```

This vector represents x-values for a plot that I am constructing. I want to superimpose each year's values on top of one another for my plot. To do so, I figure that I have to split this `samp` vector by whole integer value.

**What is the easiest way to do so ?**

---

The only solution I have come up with is taking a sequence for all of the years with

```
years <- seq(floor(min(samp)),
             ceiling(max(samp)))
```

and then looping through the years and indexing to find the values belonging to each year. There feels like there should be some way to cut my vector up by year like this more easily than an explicit loop, though.

Comment: `floor(samp)` ?

Comment: `split(samp, floor(samp))` ?

Comment: Oh.. wow. That is incredibly simple. My apologies, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just make my comment into an answer:
You are looking for the `split` function (see `?split` to check out some examples)
It takes as arguments your vector and a vector of the same length of factors (numeric is OK) defining how to group the values. The output of `split` is a list.

```
samp = c(1959.000 ,1959.083 ,1959.167 ,1959.250, 1960.000 ,1960.083)
split(samp, floor(samp))
#### $`1959`
#### [1] 1959.000 1959.083 1959.167 1959.250
#### 
#### $`1960`
#### [1] 1960.000 1960.083
```